# JQuery change CSS property of two div's

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two `div`'s in my HTML `modal-footer` & `modal-header` and I want to change the background color of these by clicking a switch.

I got the switch from a ww3schools tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp) and I want the background color to change, when I switch it.

HTML of the switch:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

I already tried something like [this](http://pastebin.com/qgkfRMX4) but it didn't work.
Anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: post your html code

Comment: It looks like you're using the toggle event http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ - this was deprecated

Comment: Use a class and use `.toggleClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like below:

use the `change()` method:

```js
$('#chk').change(function() {
    // this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if (this.checked) {
        //alert("checked");
        $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#001133");
    } else {
        $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
    }
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
<div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#ff0000">
qwerty
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without braces:

```
$(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#001133");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple, drawn out way of doing it.  I've added a pseudo toggle class to switch when you click on it.  If it doesn't have the class `.on`, then give it the class on (also, change the background-color).  If it does, remove it and change the background colors.

```
$('.switch').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(".modal-header").css({"background-color", "#001133"});
        $(".modal-footer").css({"background-color", "#001133"});
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(".modal-header").css({"background-color", "#6699ff"});
        $(".modal-footer").css({"background-color", "#6699ff"});
    }
}
```

A simpler way is to make your CSS work for you:

```
body .modal-header,
body .modal-footer {
    background-color: #6699ff;
}

body.on .modal-header,
body.on .modal-footer {
    background-color: #001133;
}
```

Then, your jQuery would look almost the same, with less lines:

```
$('.switch').click(function() {
    if($(body).hasClass('on')) {
        $(body).removeClass('on');
    } else {
        $(body).addClass('on');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your anwser. I tried replacing my code with yours but it still didn't work.   Do you have  any other solution?  I  don't either really get what you mean with the class "on". I don't have any class called "on".

Comment: you can write even shorter code: `$(body).toggleClass('on', !$(body).hasClass('on'));`

Comment: @Banzay, Correct, though seeing his code, I figured he's sort of in the beginning stages and I wanted to show him the breakdown before it got too complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably simplify further by just using toggleClass to apply/remove a CSS class which alters the stlyes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".switch").click(function() {
      $(".modal-header, .modal-footer").toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-header.active{
  background-color: #001133;
}
.modal-footer.active{
  background-color: #6699ff;
}

/*  Or if you want to toggle both between the two colours at the same time you could use the CSS below  */
/*
.modal-header, .modal-footer{
    background-color: #001133;
}
.modal-header.active, .modal-footer.active{
      background-color: #6699ff;
}

*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-header">header</div>
<div class="modal-footer">footer</div>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.css()` jquery function to change `background-color`

```
$('.switch').click(function() {
    $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".modal-footer").css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```